Miirym, Sentinel Wyrm entering the field at the same time
So, I have Miirym, Sentinel Wyrm and a lot of other dragons in the Graveyard. I cast Eerie Ultimatum bringing all permanents back which cause a lot of ETB effects to go off but would Miirym, Sentinel Wyrm see all of them enter and make copies of all the dragons that entered with it? This question also applies to Lathliss, Dragon Queen and the potential copy that is made off Miirym, Sentinel Wyrm.

Note that the token copies are not created until the relevant Miirym ability resolves, so the token Lathliss can only see tokens etb, no matter how you order the triggers.

Yes, they will trigger.
For reference, see rule 603.6a:

603.6a Enters-the-battlefield abilities trigger when a permanent enters the battlefield. These are written, “When [this object] enters
the battlefield, . . . ” or “Whenever a [type] enters the battlefield,
. . .” Each time an event puts one or more permanents onto the
battlefield, all permanents on the battlefield (including the
newcomers) are checked for any enters-the-battlefield triggers that
match the event.

